# how to insert 2 arrays with createmany in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a relationship that i try to insert with the relationship into the model every thing is fine when i just add phone numbers but when i add the secound field which is type_id i cant handle it because it wont insert the secound field into table here is how i do it in my controller store i want my user to be able to send unlimited phone numbers and each of them have a type_id how can i achive that 
:

```
  public function store(StoreHome $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->all();
        if (!$validated) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validated->errors());
        }

        $home = Home::create($validated);
        $phones = [];
        $type_id = [];
        $numbers = $request->input('phones');
        $type_id = $request->input('type_id');
        foreach($numbers as $number => $item){
            $phones[] = [
                'phone' => $number
            ];
            $types[] = [
              $type_id[] = [
                  'type_id' => $type_id[$item]
              ]
            ];
        }

        $home->phones()->createMany($phones);


        return new HomeResource($home);
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `$phones` to `createMany`, this variable does not contain any `type_id` because you put them into `$types` variable which, moreover is not declared (I suppose you mispelled `$type_id = [];` instead of `$types = [];`

Answer (score 0):

Example solution;

```
$datas = [];
foreach($numbers as $number => $item){
    array_push($datas, [$number =>  $type_id[$item]]);
}

foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
    Home::create([
        'phone' => $key,
        'type_id' => $value
    ]);
}
```